# How to solve noise issue when using airpods (2nd gen) over Zoom?

Tags: macbook-pro, audio, big-sur, airpods, video-conference

When I use airpods (2nd generation, NOT the pro) during remote meetings over Zoom, I can hear a "du..du.." noise intermittently and some light (but more constant) background noise. Such noise does not appear at all when I use these airpods over other applications, say YouTube or Music. I have two pairs of airpods (2nd gen) and both have the same issue. I also have a pair of first-gen airpods, which also has some noise problem with Zoom but is much less noticeable. I am using Macbook Pro (Early 2015 version, running Big Sur: version 11.0.1).

Moreover, if I use wired earphones or let the audio play directly out of the computer's speaker, there is no such noise at all during Zoom conference calls. To sum up, the scenarios are:

[image]

Is this a common issue? Where does the cause lie (Airods? Zoom? Operating System?) Is there anyway to resolve this problem?

Comment: I don’t have an answer, but I just want to add that it’s not just you: I hear the same thing on Zoom calls with my 2nd-gen AirPods. It doesn’t always happen, but when it does, it’s always with Zoom specifically and not any other apps, and only through the AirPods and not my laptop’s built-in speakers. I have a 2014 MacBook Pro running Big Sur 11.2.3.